# Powershell and passing metacharacters through select-string -Allmatches (2.0)

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to write / modify a function to cleanup illegal filenames on a windows filesystem (put there by the OS X clients of our network). The script works just fine however when trying to pass certain metacharacters in regex, the check performed in -AllMatches returns false for a positive match (using folders intentionally named illegally for testing). If characters are done individually (not using the loop provided) they return true. I have tried every method of escaping (and combination of the two, \ and `), with no luck. Other special characters work fine (such as &).

Anyone have any thoughts as to why it behaves this way? (Note: the two declarations for illegal characters that are commented out below are broken up into characters that don't work,  and characters that do.

```
function Check-IllegalCharacters ($Path, [switch]$Fix, [switch]$Verbose)
{
Write-Host Checking files in $Path, please wait...
#Get all files and folders under the path specified
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse
foreach ($item in $items)
{
    #Check if the item is a file or a folder
    if ($item.PSIsContainer) { $type = "Folder" }
    else { $type = "File" }

    #Report item has been found if verbose mode is selected
    if ($Verbose) { Write-Host Found a $type called $item.FullName }

    #Check if item name is 128 characters or more in length
    if ($item.Name.Length -gt 127)
    {
        Write-Host $type $item.Name is 128 characters or over and will need to be truncated -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else
    {
    #$illegalChars = '[<>?*|/\:"]'    $illegalChars = '[&{}~#%]'
        #Got this from http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2011/05/20/finding-multiple-regex-matches.aspx
        $illegalChars = '[&{}~#%]'
        filter Matches($illegalChars)
        {
            $item.Name | Select-String -AllMatches $illegalChars |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty Values

        }

        #Replace illegal characters with legal characters where found
        $newFileName = $item.Name
        Matches $illegalChars | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host $type $item.FullName has the illegal character $_.Value -ForegroundColor Red
            #These characters may be used on the file system but not SharePoint
            if ($_.Value -match "&") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "&", "and") }
            if ($_.Value -match "{") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "{", "(") }
            if ($_.Value -match "}") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "}", ")") }
            if ($_.Value -match "~") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "~", "-") }
            if ($_.Value -match "#") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "#", "") }
            if ($_.Value -match "%") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "%", "") }
        }

        #Check for start, end and double periods
        if ($newFileName.StartsWith(".")) { Write-Host $type $item.FullName starts with a period -ForegroundColor red }
        while ($newFileName.StartsWith(".")) { $newFileName = $newFileName.TrimStart(".") }
        if ($newFileName.EndsWith(".")) { Write-Host $type $item.FullName ends with a period -ForegroundColor Red }
        while ($newFileName.EndsWith("."))   { $newFileName = $newFileName.TrimEnd(".") }
        if ($newFileName.Contains("..")) { Write-Host $type $item.FullName contains double periods -ForegroundColor red }
        while ($newFileName.Contains(".."))  { $newFileName = $newFileName.Replace("..", ".") }

        #Fix file and folder names if found and the Fix switch is specified
        if (($newFileName -ne $item.Name) -and ($Fix))
        {
            Rename-Item $item.FullName -NewName ($newFileName)
            Write-Host $type $item.Name has been changed to $newFileName -ForegroundColor Blue
        }
    }
}
}
```

Much thanks if anyone is able to help!

EDIT: For further clarification, the function here works fine as-is, it's only when changing the regex expression (and escaping where necessary) to the other variant $illegalChars = '[<>?*|/\:"]' that it no longer functions correctly. It will run just fine, no errors, however it will not catch any file or folders with those characters in them.

The function can be loaded, and then run by executing 'Check-IllegalCharacters -Path $path -Verbose'

Comment: "Select-Object -ExpandProperty Values" is "Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value" right? and in filter are missing some '|', right?

Comment: The WPS in Action by Bruce Payette says there are many cases when you need 4 \` chars (or was it 5? :-) to do escaping properly. Did you try that? Just starting to read the book and don't have time to check for it now. Good luck.

Comment: Without digging into the code... Any reason why you use select-string here instead of tool designed for filtering, where-object?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the here under example you have to use the '\' in the the left place of the replace operator when the caracter is a Regex meta caracter. The switch `-regex` option can help you.

```
clear-host
$stringTotest = "coucou & Bonjour {vous} [<>?*|/\:`"]"

switch -regex ($stringTotest)
{
    "&"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '&', 'et'
    }
    "{"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '{', '('
    }
    "{"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '}', ')'
    }
    "\["
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '\[', '1'
    }
    "<"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '<', '2'
    }
    ">"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '>', '3'
    }
    "\?"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '\?', '4'
    } 
    "\*"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '\*', '5'
    }
    "\|"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '\|', '6'
    }
    "/"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '/', '7'
    }  
    "\\"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '\\', '8'
    }    
    ":"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace ':', '9'
    }      
    "`""
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '"', '0'
    }    
    "\]"
  {
        $stringTotest = $stringTotest -replace '\]', '1'
    }    
    default
  {
        break
    }
}

$stringTotest
```